# Download and upload from different router using eth0 and wlan0 connection

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, router, ethernet

I have 2 modems, one with 5 mbps upload and another one with 8 mbps download. Is it possible to connect one from wlan0 and another from eth0 interface and use one of interfaces for download and another for upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using route command. One of datas is from stable ip, and I'm routing all request for this ip to modem connected in wlan0 interface. And everything else stays in eth0. Works very well

Answer (score 0):

Not really, no. Not without the ISP(s) on the other end of those broadband links also doing special work to make sure your data gets to you correctly.